# IIS application pool setting Throttle under load

Tags: iis, cpu-usage

One of our customers has set the application pool to throttle under load at 35%, and at times they noticed the following event

Event ID:  5210 
CPU time for application pool 'abc' has been throttled.

They noticed such events show up in the event viewer log, even though the CPU utilization on the web server is not pegged high, for example < 60%

Would like to know:

•   Under what condition does the event id 5210 get generated?

•   How does IIS detect contention on the CPU?  Is it based on a performance counter etc?

Comment: Is your issue solved?
If your issue is solved then I request you to mark the helpful suggestion as an answer. This will help other people who face the same issue.
If your issue still exists then try to refer the solution given by the community members.If then also you have any further questions then let us know about it.
We will try to provide further suggestions to solve the issue.

Comment: Hi..I would just like to know the following:
1.) Under what condition does the event id 5210 get generated?

2.) How does IIS detect contention on the CPU? Is it based on a performance counter etc?

Comment: Event id i mentioned is 5210..

Comment: sorry for the misunderstanding. the cause of the issue is your application pool misconfiguration.you could refer this link for how CPU throttling work in iis https://blogs.iis.net/shauneagan/cpu-throttling-iis-7-vs-iis-8.

Answer (score 1):

The cause of the issue is there is something misconfiguration with your Application Pool.

- open iis manager.
- Right-click on the appropriate Application Pool and click Advanced Settings.
- Set the Limit to 0 and Limit Action value to NoAction.

[image]

[IIS 8.0 CPU Throttling: Sand-boxing Sites and Applications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/whats-new-in-iis-8/iis-80-cpu-throttling-sand-boxing-sites-and-applications)

Answer (score 0):

This is strange question: you said you had set AppPool to ThrottleUnderLoad and set Limit to 35%. Why do you wonder when it hits the limit and generates a log record? The most common value for the throttle limit is 80%, which allows to throttle the load a little when there are too many requests and the CPU resources are not enough. I don't see sense to set the limit to 35%, this will slow web responses from your server when it has plenty of CPU time.

I suggest increasing the value. This would decrease the number of 5210 warnings.

Comment: Documented behaviour of ThrottleUnderLoad (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/whats-new-in-iis-8/iis-80-cpu-throttling-sand-boxing-sites-and-applications) is to throttle only when CPU is in contention. Supporting commentary: (https://blogs.iis.net/shauneagan/cpu-throttling-iis-7-vs-iis-8) suggests that load needs to be applied for this to happen. Perhaps the max CPU exceeded the throttle limit, but average didn't? (Just a thought on metric management)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).